# AttributeError: 'Celery' object has no attribute '_config_source'

Tags: python, python-3.x, celery

I'm working on a linux (fedora) machine and I want to use celery in python3.3.
When i execute these command:

```
celery -A tasks worker --loglevel=info
celery worker --help
```

I get the following error:

```
    [root@localhost gert]# celery -A tasks worker --loglevel=info
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.3/site-packages/celery-3.1.0rc1-py3.3.egg/celery/bin/base.py", line 399, in find_app
    sym = self.symbol_by_name(app)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.3/site-packages/celery-3.1.0rc1-py3.3.egg/celery/bin/base.py", line 418, in symbol_by_name
    return symbol_by_name(name, imp=import_from_cwd)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.3/site-packages/kombu-2.5.9-py3.3.egg/kombu/utils/__init__.py", line 80, in symbol_by_name
    module = imp(module_name, package=package, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.3/site-packages/celery-3.1.0rc1-py3.3.egg/celery/utils/imports.py", line 87, in import_from_cwd
    return imp(module, package=package)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.3/importlib/__init__.py", line 88, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1577, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1558, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1525, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 586, in _check_name_wrapper
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1023, in load_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1004, in load_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 562, in module_for_loader_wrapper
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 869, in _load_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 313, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/gert/tasks.py", line 3, in <module>
    celery = Celery('tasks', broker='amqp://guest@localhost//')
  File "/usr/lib/python3.3/site-packages/celery-3.1.0rc1-py3.3.egg/celery/app/base.py", line 131, in __init__
    if self._config_source:
AttributeError: 'Celery' object has no attribute '_config_source'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/celery", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('celery==3.1.0rc1', 'console_scripts', 'celery')()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.3/site-packages/celery-3.1.0rc1-py3.3.egg/celery/__main__.py", line 30, in main
    main()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.3/site-packages/celery-3.1.0rc1-py3.3.egg/celery/bin/celery.py", line 77, in main
    cmd.execute_from_commandline(argv)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.3/site-packages/celery-3.1.0rc1-py3.3.egg/celery/bin/celery.py", line 709, in execute_from_commandline
    super(CeleryCommand, self).execute_from_commandline(argv)))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.3/site-packages/celery-3.1.0rc1-py3.3.egg/celery/bin/base.py", line 260, in execute_from_commandline
    argv = self.setup_app_from_commandline(argv)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.3/site-packages/celery-3.1.0rc1-py3.3.egg/celery/bin/base.py", line 388, in setup_app_from_commandline
    self.app = self.find_app(app)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.3/site-packages/celery-3.1.0rc1-py3.3.egg/celery/bin/base.py", line 402, in find_app
    sym = import_from_cwd(app)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.3/site-packages/celery-3.1.0rc1-py3.3.egg/celery/utils/imports.py", line 87, in import_from_cwd
    return imp(module, package=package)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.3/importlib/__init__.py", line 88, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1577, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1558, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1525, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 586, in _check_name_wrapper
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1023, in load_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1004, in load_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 562, in module_for_loader_wrapper
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 869, in _load_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 313, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/gert/tasks.py", line 3, in <module>
    celery = Celery('tasks', broker='amqp://guest@localhost//')
  File "/usr/lib/python3.3/site-packages/celery-3.1.0rc1-py3.3.egg/celery/app/base.py", line 131, in __init__
    if self._config_source:
AttributeError: 'Celery' object has no attribute '_config_source'
```

I already installed the required packages so my site-packages map in python3.3 looks like this:

- celery-3.1.0rc1-py3.3.egg
- amqp-1.2.0-py3.3
- anyjson-0.3.3-py3.3.egg
- billiard-3.3.0.0rc1-py3.3.egg
- distribute-0.6.28-py3.3.egg-info
- easy_install.py
- kombu-2.5.9-py3.3.egg
- pip-1.2.1-py3.3.egg-info
- pkg_resources.py
- pycache (with underscores)
- python_dateutil-2.0-py3.3.egg
- pytz-2013b-py3.3.egg
- setuptools
- setuptools-0.6c11-py3.3.egg-info
- site.py
- six-1.3.0-py3.3.egg

does anyone know what I'm missing, or what I've done wrong?

Comment: Please include the *full* traceback of the error.

Comment: You must be using the dev version of Celery, right? Since 3.1 hasn't yet been released. It is quite possible that you hit a bug that still needs correcting, did you file an issue with [Celery issue tracker](https://github.com/celery/celery/issues)?

Comment: i didn't yet, because the exact same installation DID work on my virtual machine. I was able to execute all of the celery commands. When I re-installed everything on my other fedora client(dual boot) it gave me this error. I did download celery from github, maybe some1 did a commit in the mean time?

Comment: I say it's quite *likely* that someone made commits in the meantime; looking at the [commit history](https://github.com/celery/celery/commits/master) Ask is quite busy.

Comment: And here is a [recent commit](https://github.com/celery/celery/commit/ed7b025ed1b5a70d9d9f802292aa710f907d8917) that touches the code affected by your traceback.

Comment: thanks for your time, I will look into that and post here if needed. I will keep you up to date of my progress.

Comment: Yeah, the master branch is often busy and since features/fixes often have to touch both celery and kombu you need to keep both of these repos up to date.  You should install the development versions of the dependencies (usually only kombu and celery change often):
$ pip install https://github.com/celery/py-amqp/zipball/master
$ pip install https://github.com/celery/billiard/zipball/master
$ pip install https://github.com/celery/kombu/zipball/master

Comment: btw, I also fixed some Python 3 related issues in the stable branch, these will be part of 3.0.18 which I'm releasing in a few hours

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As martijn said, the answer is simple.
Someone did a commit to the celery project in github, I pulled my previous version and now it works. 
This error shouldn't be much of a problem when they get it fixed.